# freeRTOS + DMA (STM32).

Tags: stm32, c, freertos

Понимаю, что форум не столь специализированный, но задам все же и тут свой вопрос. Вполне вероятно кто-нибудь подскажет.
Есть простая работающая программа - freeRTOS + мигание диодом (там еще небольшая лабуда есть, но не суть), платформа - STM32(F217).
Решил попробовать добавить USART + DMA. Инициализация проходит в следующем порядке:

1. порты GPIO (для диодов);
2. контроллер NVIC (для лабуды =));
3. DMA :

   ```
   RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);

   DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Stream7 );
   DMA_InitTypeDef DMA_InitStructure;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_4;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = USART1_BASE + offsetof(USART_TypeDef, DR);
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (u32) buffer;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_MemoryToPeripheral;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = strlen(buffer);
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
   DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_VeryHigh;
   //DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
   DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream7, &DMA_InitStructure);`
   ```
4. USART:

   ```
   USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;   //для инициализации USART

   GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);

   //настроить выводы, к которым подключены RX и TX
   RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);   //тактирование GPIOA
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;          //линия RX
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN; //вход, третье состояние
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);             //выполнить инициализацию
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;           //линия TX
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;     //макс частота сигнала
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;      //симетричный выход
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);             //выполнить инициализацию

   //настройка модуля USART
   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);
   USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 115200;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No ;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl =
    USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
   USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
   USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStructure);
   ```
5. DMA + USART:

   ```
   USART_DMACmd(USART1, USART_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);
   USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);
   DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream7, ENABLE);
   ```

Собственно если закоментить инициализацию DMA начальный вариант программы (мигание диодом) работает как ему и положено. А вот если раскоментить - светодиод тупо загорается и на этом все. Т.е. задача (а скорее шедулер) висит.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: а если попробовать DMA_Mode и DMA_Priority изменить? Не может быть, что у Вас ДМА циклически читается с самым высоким приоритетом?

Comment: Идея интересная. Посмотрю чуть позже. Подумаю.

Comment: Все таки нет. DMA кроме как для этого нигде не используется. Приоритет этот - приоритет сугубо потоков DMA, а не прерываний. Да и прерывания не генерятся. Поэтому DMA работает (должен работать) в фоне чисто аппаратно (бе участия ядра) и никак не должен влиять на оставшуюся часть программы. Если я нигде не ошибся.

Comment: @decodder, лично никогда не писал  с DMA, но всегда считал, что по завершению операции DMA вызывает прерывание (а его ядро должно обрабатывать).

Вот это, правда, мне не очень понятно

    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;

Что  тут должно происходить?

Кстати, а аппаратный приоритет доступа к шине памяти выше у CPU или DMA?

--

Конкретно (к сожалению) ничего сказать не могу (с freertos дела тоже никогда не имел).

Comment: DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular; - означает, что по завершении передачи буфера, передача возобновляется с нулевого адреса и так по кругу. Собственно пробовал менять на режим однократной передачи - результат тот же.
По поводу приоритета доступа к шине почему-то думаю, что у CPU приоритет выше, но это догадки. Попробую еще на самом деле слабать пример без RTOS и проверить. Связи может (скорее всего) и нет. Потом отпишусь.

Comment: @decodder, [вот в этой статье](http://www.netdocs.ru/articles/direct-memory-access.html) пишут, что в burst режиме работы DMA процессор работает только с кэшем. 

Посмотрите, что у Вас?

Comment: @avp, в нашем случае single-cycle. Спасибо за статью, кстати, интересно.

Comment: Попробуйте сначала осуществить передачу без DMA. У меня есть подозрение, что неправильно инициализированы ноги RX и TX. Не работал с серией STM32F2xx, но в сериях STM32F0xx, 1xx, 4xx нужно дополнительно сконфигурировать ногу как альтернативную функцию. Может быть в этом дело? Если без DMA проблема повторится, то моя гипотеза подтвердится. А вообще, не пробовали в отладчике посмотреть, что там происходит? Может быть, он в HardFault падает.

Comment: Пины USARTа должны быть определены как Alternative Funtions

Comment: Ссылка, данная пользователем @avp, «умерла». Вот архивированный вариант: https://web.archive.org/web/20140812222222/http://netdocs.ru/articles/direct-memory-access.html.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что вы не правильно пины настроили для юсарта.
Их надо настраивать как Alternative Functions.
Так же вот в этой `DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr` можно поставить просто `USART1->DR` и все:

```
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = USART1->DR;
```

Сообщите пожалуйста, получилось ли...
А почему вы не используете MXCube? Конечно подход с HALом немного другой, но зато работает постабильней чем SPL...